# Use Facebook API to list group members' join date and inviter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can use the Facebook Graph API to get a list of group members. The simplest way to do this is to go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and do a GET request of the form `{group_id}/members`. Is there a way to similarly obtain the members' join date and who they were invited by?

The [relevant Graph API doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) doesn't seem to mention it. But I know the information is stored by Facebook because it is possible to list all of the group members and their inviters through Facebook itself. Is there a way to get this information through the API?

EDIT: Nothing in the FQL [group](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group/) or [group_member](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group_member) API either.

Answer (score 1):

While this information is not available on the API, you can get it by using Selenium to scrape the members page. 
First, instantiate a driver and use it to get the members page:

`driver.gethttps://www.facebook.com/groups/your group number/members`

Then, look for the member information:

`containers = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')`

Finally, iterate through the web elements, extracting text and parsing resulting list for joined date information:

```
member_info = container.text.split('\n')
name = member_info[0]
member_since = member_info[-1]
```

You'll still have to map this information to the user ids, which you can do by looking for another element in the container and using REGEX.

```
`def parse_id(self, container, name):
        hovercard = container.find_element_by_link_text(name).get_attribute('data-hovercard')
        regex_id = re.compile('php\?id=(\d*)')
        member_id = regex_id.search(hovercard).group(1)
        return member_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed stored by Facebook and retrieved for use with internal APIs. For the Graph API however it is not possible to get this information.

All the fields available for a `group_member` are listed at `SELECT column_name FROM column WHERE table_name = "group_member"`